# jQuery JSON into HTML existing list

Tags: jquery, json

I wonder if I'm doing this correctly, but I want that for every existing list add data from json.

The json file looks like:

```
{
   val1:key1,
   val2:key2,
   val3:key3
}
```

Lets call file `test.json`.

And I have an existing list, I made a version of the code that creates a list  from scratch from the data, but after adding a few more items the dom gets too nested.

HTML is:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script scr="jquery.js></script>
</head>
<body>
    <main id="wrapper">
       <ul id="menu">
           <li class="test"><a>Item1</a></li>
           <li class="test"><a>Item2</a></li>
           <li class="test"><a>Item3</a></li>
       </ul>
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

So my first script was:

```
$.getJSON("test.json", function (data) {
    var items = [];
    $.each(data,function (key,val) {
        items.push("<li id='"+key+"'>"+"<a href='#'>"+key+"</a>"+"<p>"+val+"</p>"+"</li>");
    });

    $( "<ul/>", {
        "class": "menu",
        html: items.join( "" )
    }).appendTo( "main#wrapper" );
})
```

Of course I had just wrapper class and it created the rest for me. But I thought that it is an impractical way to do it and wanted to add just

into  the existing lis. So I almost did it... but I don't know seem to be getting it right...

```
$.getJSON("test.json",function (data) {
    $.each(data,function (key,val) {
       $('<li.test>').html(
           "<p>" + val + "</p>"
       ).appendTo('ul#menu li')
    });
});
```

It works in the sense that it adds p tags into my li but each li gets all  the data.

Comment: Something is wrong on this line `}).appendTo( "main#wrapper" );`

Comment: @AniketSahrawat Well this code work for me, the problem is I build whole list in one query ;/ And it getting too hard to read and modify.

Comment: It seems you are appending the li to another li. Try appending your li to the ul directly with: 'appendTo('ul#menu')' (instead of appendTo('ul#menu li') )

Comment: @cloned When i remove li from appendTo('ul#menu li') it add elements one time but, not in li. In the end I want something like:

Test1
* Value1
Test2
* Value2
Test3
*Value3

And when i remove li I Have

Test1
Test2
Test3

*value1
*value2
*value3

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be the selector you're choosing for the list items(li).

```
$('<li.test>').html(...)
```

This changes the html for all list items at the same time.

The first code sample you provided seem to working fine to what you want to do,since you may not know the exact number of objects from the json file.

But if you do then something like this would work....

```
$("li.test").each(function(index){
  $(this).html("<p>" + data[index] + "</p>")
})
```

Comment: Yea working 100%, just hard like omg I need to add something else, and item + item + item + item+ item... and it went like too many to edit it normaly. I will try your solution.

Comment: Please let us know if it worked, otherwise we can try and find a different solution.

Comment: Sorry, was trying to find the other way :). It didn't work sadly. I couldnt append any string with this method.